# Working with Django LocalFlavor Zip as a Model Field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

What's the best way to implement the following:

```
### models.py
>>> from django.db import models
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create the client class.
>>> class Client(models.Model):
...     user = models.OntToOneField(User)
...     zip = ***???***()

### forms.py
>>> from django.forms import ModelForm
# Create the form class.
>>> class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
...     class Meta:
...         model = Client
```

I'm trying to get the end result to use the [US Zip Codes Field form widget/validator](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/localflavor/#django.contrib.localflavor.us.forms.USZipCodeField) using only modifications the models.py file... aka I don't want to do the following:

```
### forms.py
>>> from django.forms import ModelForm
>>> from django.contrib.localflavor.us.forms import USZipCodeField
# Create the form class.
>>> class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
...     class Meta:
...         model = Client
...     zip = USZipCodeField()
```

NOTE: It might be that the BEST way to accomplish it is in the forms.py file as shown above... If this is the case, I guess I'm missing the argument/benefit of having it there instead of as a custom model field (e.g., DRY?, loose coupling?) Any help on helping better understand the benefits of forms.py over models.py in this scenario would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!
-Tom

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A zip code is just a string of numbers/letters, so there's no need to define a custom field for storing it in the database. There's no model-level validation in Django at the moment (although there's a Google Summer of Code project to add it), so a custom model field wouldn't add anything. The validation comes at the form level, which is why there's a custom form field.

Answer (score 0):

This must not have been available when you asked the question, but django 1.4 has `django.contrib.localflavor.us.models.USPostalCodeField()`, which you'd think would do what you need, but it is designed for storing those 2-letter state abbreviations, not Zip Codes, unfortunately.